# How to use the default value for an attribute set in nixos, and extend it

Tags: attributes, set, default, nixos

The default value for `programs.zsh.shellAliases` is

```
 { l = "ls -alh"; ll = "ls -l"; ls = "ls --color=tty"; }
```

which is nice.

I want to extend the attribute set with

```
{ xclip = "xclip -selection clipboard"; paste = "xclip -out"; }
```

I know I can merge attribute sets with `//` and, because I know the default, I can just write down my desired attribute set explicitly.

But is it possible to keep the default and extend it like this:

```
 programs.zsh.shellAliases = [default] // { ... };
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value is available in `options.programs.zsh.shellAliases.default`.

You can play around with it in `nix-repl`:

```
nix-repl> (import <nixpkgs/nixos> { configuration = {lib, options, ...}: { config.programs.zsh.shellAliases = options.programs.zsh.shellAliases.default // { xclip = "xclip -selection clipboard"; paste = "xclip -out"; }; }; }).config.programs.zsh.shellAliases
{ l = "ls -alh"; ll = "ls -l"; ls = "ls --color=tty"; paste = "xclip -out"; xclip = "xclip -selection clipboard"; }
```

Comment: I added "options" to the parameter list on top of my `configuration.nix` and it works.